# Passing two props from parent to child component leads to undefined in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

In my react redux project, I am trying to pass props from a child component to a parent component. More specifically, I want to pass two pieces of information: product and counter, to the parent container, where both pieces of information are intended to be used inside the function, like this:

```
addProductToBasket(product, counter) {

}
```

My problem is this: counter is not recognised in the addProductToBasket function, and I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: counter is not defined

Why isn't counter defined here, and how can I properly use it inside this function?

Here is the relevant parent container code:

```
class Products extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            listOn: false,
            total: 0,
        }

        this.addProductToBasket = this.addProductToBasket.bind(this);
    }

    addProductToBasket(product, counter) {
        var price = Number(product.price);
        console.log(price);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            total: prevState.total + price,
        }), 
        () => {
            var total = this.state.total
            console.log(counter);
            this.props.updateBasket(total, price, counter, product);
        })  
    }

    render() {
        const grid = this.props.products.map((product, i) => {
            return (
                <GridLayout
                    key={i}
                    name={product.name}
                    id={product.id}
                    description={product.description}
                    price={product.price}
                    addProductToBasket={() => this.addProductToBasket(product, counter)}
                />
            );
        });

        return(
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                      {grid}
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        products: state.products
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ updateBasket: updateBasket }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

and the child component code:

```
export default class GridLayout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
        }

        this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    }

    handleAdd(product) {
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1}, () => {
            var counter = this.state.counter
            console.log('counter is' + counter)
            this.props.addProductToBasket(product, counter);
        });  
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Col xs={12} md={4}>
                <div style={{padding: '10px', backgroundColor: 'white', height: '120px', width: '100%'}}>
                    <div>{this.props.id}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.name}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.description}</div>
                    <div>$ {this.props.price}</div>
                    <div style={{float: 'right', cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={this.handleAdd}>
                        +
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you forgot to receive the parameters passed from child inside parent component in arrow function.

Here:

```
addProductToBasket={() => this.addProductToBasket(product, counter)}
```

Use this:

```
addProductToBasket={(prodt, counter) => this.addProductToBasket(prodt, counter)}
```

**Reason is:** You are not passing the `addProductToBasket` directly to child, you are passing **[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**, and inside the body of arrow function you are calling `addProductToBasket`, so you need to receive the parameters in arrow function and pass those parameters to addProductToBasket.

**Other Possible solution is:**

Remove the arrow function and write it like this:

```
addProductToBasket={ this.addProductToBasket }
```

Comment: facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
addProductToBasket={() => this.addProductToBasket(product, counter)}
```

With this:

```
addProductToBasket={this.addProductToBasket.bind(this, product, counter)}
```